# Maven POM local intellij module dependencies conflict

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module, dependencies

I have a Java project in intellij where I'm running JSF with a JBoss/wildfly run configuration.
In my project structure, I have many modules. Of those many modules, 4 of them are made into exploded WAR artifacts. I'm able to deploy these artifacts and run them properly via intellij's run config.

This project defines dependencies for the modules in pom.xml files per module. I am trying to build and explode these modules in the WAR format using maven instead of intellij.

My problem is that when running `mvn clean install` on the first module that I wish to generate the WAR folder for, I'm getting an error in the format "Could not find artifact ... (https://some.repo.com)". It shouldn't be looking for this dependency externally, as it exists in my intellij project as a module. Intellij is able to correctly identify it as a module dependency (in my project structure) for the module that I am trying to generate the WAR file for.

The POM file I'm using simply has a dependency section with a groupid, artifactid and version. How do I configure it to recognise that this is a "local module" dependency? Also, if my process or assumptions above about the generation of an exploded WAR file are wrong, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. I missed the pom at the root of the project which contained the module information.